# How to add String list view ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

am scan Qr code/Barcode, so I want to scan different qr code/barcode and arrange them is String listview.

Example I want to `setText()` like this `,scanNumber1,scanNumber2,....,...,` so far i have managed to scan that Qr Code/Barcode but when i scan the next number it remove the first one, so I want ti arrange those number.

here is my code

```
public void scanCode(View view){
    IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       String scanNumber=intentResult.getContents();
    if (intentResult != null) {

        if(intentResult.getContents() == null) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scan The QR code/Barcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

        }
        //validate ur scan numbers
        else if (intentResult.getContents().length() == 10) {
            textView1.setText(intentResult.getContents());
        }
        else if(intentResult.getContents().length() == 12){
            textView2.setText(intentResult.getContents());
        }
        else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That Number is Out Of Our Range", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

and this is output
[image]

so I want on that `Slave` to appear like `,scanNumber1,scanNumber2,....,...,`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a global JointoString function object to achieve the desired behaviour i.e. "barcode1","barcode2"....

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>()
```

when you receive the result try

```
results.add(<value>)
```

while displaying to text view use

```
textView.setText(results.joinToString(","))
```

Comment: brother, the first line `


you can use a global JointoString function object to achieve the desired behaviour i.e. "barcode1","barcode2"....

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>()` i put where, onCreate method or ?

Comment: if you would like to see my code you can link my zoom,

Join Zoom Meeting
https://zoom.us/j/96095658643?pwd=eTU3d3VEOTlFazU1RzB3eWJzMk41dz09

Meeting ID: 960 9565 8643
Password: 5nvWbe

Comment: you can create it as private class property , i.e. outside of onCreate()

Comment: Brother, can you show me how? I dont have big experience of in android studio

Comment: If you are interested i can show you my code and once is works then you can update the answer here